# Кнопки Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment

Код кнопки

```
    private lateinit var wifiViewModel: WifiViewModel
    private var _binding: FragmentWifiBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        wifiViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(WifiViewModel::class.java)

        _binding = FragmentWifiBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        val textView: TextView = binding.textWifi
        wifiViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            textView.text = it
        })

        val generateButton: Button = binding.generateBtn
        generateButton.setOnClickListener(){
            qrCodeImage.setImageBitmap(getQrCodeBitmap("f"))
        }

        return root
    }
```

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/generateBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:onClick="onGenerateBtnClick"
        android:text="Generate!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Если я пишу эту функцию в в тот фрагмент, в котором кнопка существует, выдается ошибка Could not find method onGenerateBtnClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton with id 'generateBtn'.

Если я пишу эту функцию в MainActivity, то студия всячески ругается, но прога работает. Куда мне все таки засунуть этот код и правильный ли он?

Comment: Напишите лучше так, программно вешая слушатель нажатий на кнопку: `view.findViewById(R.id.generateBtn).setOnClickListener{ qrCodeImage.setImageBitmap(getQrCodeBitmap("f")) }`

Comment: Так, уже пробовал. Куда это засунуть?

Comment: В фрагменте не работает, выдает ошибку Not enough information to infer type variable T

Comment: Попробуйте это поместить в `onViewCreated(view: View)` метод, например. Чтобы компилилось, попробуйте тип указать так: `findViewById<Button>(R.id.generateBtn)`

Comment: Хмм, компилится, ошибок не выдает, но при нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит

Comment: Код надо текстом, не картинкой. Так никто не сможет вам скопировать кусок вашего кода и исправленную версию написать. Программисты ленивые и не любят набирать большие объёмы кода, т.к. IDE обычно после первых 2 символов набранных уже предлагает нужный вариант в автодополнении. Раз у вас ViewBinding используется, то замените view.findViewById(R.id.generateBtn) на аналог из биндинга. ПОсле этого добавьте вывод в логи чего-то из слушателя клика. Если в логах что-то будет - значит слушатель работает. После этого проверьте, что ваша вьюха для картинки работает.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, добавил исправленный вариант

Comment: Значит ли это, что у вас всё заработало? :-)

Comment: Кнопка работает, теперь другая часть программы не работает))))